# PostgreSQL Table not using index on date column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE a (a_id int), (my_date date)
CREATE INDEX idx_my_date ON a USING BTREE (my_date)
```

The table has about 140M rows and I am trying to query the table by a `BETWEEN` date query... and for some reason it isn't using the index on `my_date`.

And I'm trying to run the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from "a" 
where "a"."my_date" >= to_date('2017-04-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
and "a"."my_date" <= to_date('2017-05-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

Aggregate  (cost=4666237.99..4666238.00 rows=1 width=8)
  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..4314558.32 rows=140671866 width=0)
        Filter: ((my_date >= to_date('2017-04-28'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text)) AND (my_date <= to_date('2017-05-03'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text)))
```

Is there anything I can do to force this query to use my index?

Comment: I was in the middle of it.. LOL

Comment: have you checked index is properly created or not ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`.  ([**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and make sure you preserve the indention of the execution plan - it's important

Answer (score 0):

If you disable seqscan, then PostrgeSQL will have to use index. You can do this with the query:

```
SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = FALSE;
```

Keep in mind that it affects only inside transaction, so if you have enabled AUTOCOMMIT then you will have to disable it or wrap everything in transaction like so:

```
BEGIN;
    SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = FALSE;
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    -- your query here
COMMIT;
```

However, even if this will work, forcing query planner to choose another plan is not the best solution, so you should consider recommendations from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html) instead.